# a simple multivariable limit

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

I get confused finding this limit.

I approach with lines $y=mx$ and i get $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2}}$. How can i ended that this limit does not exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit does not exist, as your approach illustrated. Notice that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+m^2x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}},$$
whose value clearly depends on $m$. That is, the limit depends on how you tend to $(0,0)$, and hence by definition the limit does not exit.

Answer (score 2):

observe that $\sqrt{x^2 + m^2 x^2} = |x| \sqrt{1 + m^2}$ and consider the cases where $x > 0$ and $x < 0$ which will give you two different limits for $\frac{x}{|x|}$

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=r \cos\theta$ and $y=r \sin\theta$, then we have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=-\lim_{r\to 0}\cos\theta$$

Thus the limit value depends on what angle you approach to point (0,0). Or a unique limit does not exist.